# How do I gain programmatic access to names in R?

Tags: r

I have an object "group"

```
> group
$Group
$Group$stats
 High   Low   Med Total 
   30    30    30    90
```

I want access to "High   Low   Med Total", and I want access to "30    30    30    90".  I do **not** want to do something hideous like hard coding in group$Group$stats, because I'm trying to write a generic routine that will pull out that information regardless of name.

How, in R, do I get access to that data in a clean manner in an R function?

Edit:

Some code I've run:

```
> names(group)
[1] "Group"
> foo <- names(group)
> foo
[1] "Group"
> group$foo
NULL
```

My definition of "clean": It is not clean to assume that you know the name of an object's element, and then hard code it into your function.  Clean is I call foo <- names (bar), and then use foo to get access to the information in bar.  How do I do that in R with S3 objects?

For those who asked:

```
> dput (group)
structure(list(Group = structure(list(stats = structure(c(30L, 30L, 30L, 90L), .Names = c("High", "Low", "Med", "Total"))), .Names = "stats")), .Names = "Group")
```

Comment: Can you show the dput output or the `str`? Have you tried by `group$Group$..`

Comment: `names` function. Read `?names`.

Comment: Your edit does not address akrun's concern (that you use `dput` to show us something concrete). Without knowing what your data looks like, we cannot suggest anything much better than the solution you call hideous.

Comment: You could easily make your data reproducible with `mylist <- list(Group=list(stats=c(High=30, Low=30, Med=30, Total=90)))`. You are looking to access a nested list. Depending on how deep your list goes, the solutions vary. So when users ask for more information, they hoping to give you a more accurate response.

Comment: @akrun Then whole point of this is I do not want to use group$Group, since that breaks if I get an object that doesn't have "Group", but has "collection" instead.

Comment: `unlist` or `rapply` might be useful.

Comment: @PierreLafortune However, for all we know, the OP only posted the first few lines of how the object is printed...

Comment: Thank you @akrun, unlist is what I was looking for. If you make that an answer, I'll mark you as solving it :-)

Comment: It's okay.  I don't post a solution without a concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the phrase I was looking for was "list slicing".  And I get proper access to the data using group[[i]]